# Draw individual Rectangles on each Mouse Click

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to draw a `Rectangle` on a `PictureBox`, but when I click on another location the `Rectangle` moves to the new location. I would like to keep the original `Rectangle` and draw a new `Rectangle` at the given coordinates.

```
private void PictureBox_Paint(...)
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x - 20, y - 10, 40, 20);
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
```

[image: Example of what I am looking for]

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE] so people are able to reproduce the problem and help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add your Rectangles to a list of rectangles.

To do so just replace :

**OnClick**

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x - 20, y - 10, 40, 20);
```

**Draw**

```
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
```

With :

**OnClick**

```
myRectangleCollection.Add(new Rectangle(x - 20, y - 10, 40, 20));
```

**Draw**

```
foreach(Rectangle rect in myRectangleCollection)
{
     e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
}
```

Just don't forget to initialize your List of rectangles in your form initialization with this :

```
List<Rectangle> myRectangleCollection = new List<Rectangle>();
```

Comment: Although I believe this is what is causing the problem, please don't guess at answers. It is hard to tell if this is what the OP needs to do with the partial snippet they have posted.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder it's a perfectly acceptable answer IMHO.

Comment: Thanks yan, it's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @Moo-Juice Perfectly acceptable answer (which I didn't argue against) yes, however, I was just encouraging the answerer not to answer crap questions because it just encourages more in the future

Comment: Do note that the collecting needs to go to the MouseClick but the drawing to the Paint event!! The way the code is presented looks quite misleading!

Comment: @TaW I totally agree with you.